# Highcharts - How to get horizontal error bars?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I am using Highcharts to chart server performance stats, memory, cpu, etc. I want to add support incidents and change windows to these charts. At first I though the error bar was perfect, but I would need to rotate them to horizontal. As far as I can see, the chart can be rotated, but only the entire chart, not one series.

```
chart: {
            type: 'spline',
            inverted: true
        },
```

Any ideas how I can get little horizontal bars on my chart, to represent the duration of incidents. Colouring according to severity wins bonus points.

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple line series, where each error bar will be separate series, but all will be connected to one master series, see example: http://jsfiddle.net/3bQne/646/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    plotOptions: {
        line: {
            color: 'red',
            lineWidth: 10,
            marker: {
                enabled: false,
                states: {
                    hover: {
                        enabled: false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'column',
        name: 'some data',
        data: [4, 11, 5, 16, 9, 22, 11, 1]        
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'errors',
        id: 'err',
        data: [ [0, 4],[3, 4]]
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'errors',
        linkedTo: 'err',
        data: [ [3, 1], [6, 1]]
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'errors',
        linkedTo: 'err',
        data: [ [2,10], [3,10]]
    }]
});
```

Answer (score -1):

use plotLines to darw lines on the chart

```
yAxis: [{
plotLines:[{
value : where do you want the line,
color: 'color for the line'
}]
}]
```

the same is possible for xAxis

if you want you can add them on demand using the method addPlotLine();

here is the example for plotLines http://jsfiddle.net/QWLhC/

```
chart.xAxis[0].addPlotLine({
value: where do you want the plotLine,
color: 'color of the plot line'
});
```